# Javascript - Creating an Array of Image Objects for canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I was trying to create an array of image objects and load the images after the windows has loaded in canvas.

Here is my code:

```
var canvasObj = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var ctx = canvasObj.getContext('2d');
var imgsrcs = ["1.png", "2.png", "3.png"];
var imgs = [];
for(var i=0; i<imgsrcs.length; i++){
    imgs[i] = new Image();
    imgs[i].onload = function () {
        ctx.drawImage(imgs[i], xb,yb);
    }
    imgs[i].src = imgsrcs[i];
}
```

however, I am getting this error in console:

```
TypeError: Argument 1 of CanvasRenderingContext2D.drawImage could not be converted to any of: HTMLImageElement, HTMLCanvasElement, HTMLVideoElement, ImageBitmap.
ctx.drawImage(imgs[i], xb,yb);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the time `onload` event is invoked, `for-loop` is iterated hence value of `i` is `length+1`, as there is no element at index `length+1`, `undefined` is passed as first argument for `ctx.drawImage`

Use `this` context in the `drawImage` method where `this` === `Image-Object`

```js
var canvasObj = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var ctx = canvasObj.getContext('2d');
var imgsrcs = ["http://i.imgur.com/gwlPu.jpg", "http://i.imgur.com/PWSOy.jpg", "http://i.imgur.com/6l6v2.png"];
var xb = 0,
  yb = 0;
var imgs = [];
for (var i = 0; i < imgsrcs.length; i++) {
  imgs[i] = new Image();
  imgs[i].onload = function() {
    console.log(imgs[i]); //Check this value
    ctx.drawImage(this, xb, yb);
    xb += 50;
    yb += 50;
  }
  imgs[i].src = imgsrcs[i];
}
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
```